# Непонятки с буферизацией ob_start()

Tags: php

Почему повторяется слово hello? Что нужно добавить, что бы нормально вывело hello world?

```
<?php

ob_start();
{
    echo "hello";
    $a = ob_get_contents();
    echo "world";
    $b = ob_get_contents();
}
ob_end_clean();

echo $a .' '. $b;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что не понятно?

Вы включили буфер, в переменную `$a` записали `hello`, но буфер-то не обновился, он записывает дальше, дальше ему приходит `world`, он это дело и записывает в `$b`, а именно `hellowrold`, Все что надо делать в вашей ситуации, это очищать буфер с помощью `ob_clean()`

```
ob_start();

echo "hello";
$a = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
echo "world";
$b = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo $a .' '. $b;
```

Доку по функции прилагаю: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-clean.php

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: Просто теории много, а примеров мало.

Comment: @DivMan всегда поможем. все норм :)